# Solving an ODE system with duplicate eigenvalues

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, systems-of-equations

I'm supposed to solve the following ODE system:

$\left\{
 \begin{array}{ll}
  \frac{dx}{dt}=11x+6y+18z\\
  \frac{dy}{dt}=9x+8y+18z\\
        \frac{dz}{dt}=-9x-6y-16z
 \end{array}
\right.$

Here is what I've done so far:
I begin by changing the problem into matrix form:

$\left(\begin{matrix}
\frac{dx}{dt}\\
\frac{dy}{dt}\\
\frac{dz}{dt}
\end{matrix}\right)$=$\left(\begin{matrix}
11&6&18\\
9&8&18\\
-9&-6&-16
\end{matrix}\right)$
$\left(\begin{matrix}
x\\
y\\
z
\end{matrix}\right)$

then finding the eigenvalues:

$\lambda_{1,2}=2, \lambda_3=-1$

and corresponding eigenvectors:

$v_1=(-2,0,1), v_2=(-2,3,0), v_3=(-1,-1,1)$

Here is where I am stuck. assuming I have done everything right so far(let me 
know if I have not), do I now just simply get each

$g_i=e^{\lambda_it}v_i$

and put them into equation

$g(t)=C_1g_1+C_1g_2+C_3g_3$

normally, or do I have to find another vector $u$ such that

$(A-\lambda I)w=v_1\wedge g_2=e^{\lambda_2}(t\cdot v_1+u)$?

If it is the second case, why do we need to do this? Why is the case of a duplicate eigenvalue special?

Comment: Why don't you check if $g_1, g_2$ and $g_3$ work? If they all do, is there anymore room for other solutions apart from linear combinations of those functions?

Comment: @GitGud what do you mean by check if they work?

Comment: Check if $g_1$ is a solution to the DE, etc.

Comment: @GitGud what is DE? duplicate eigenvalue?

Comment: $v_1$ does not seem to be an eigenvector (as a column vector). Do you know Jordan Normal Form?

Comment: $v_2$ and $v_3$ seem to be wrong as well. Is the square matrix that you typed in correctly typed?

Comment: @WillJagy There was a typo. fixing it now! sorry about that

Comment: @CluelessButCurious DE stands for differential equation. Check if $g_1$ is a solution. To the same for the others.

Comment: @GitGud I'm sorry, but I'm honestly not really sure how to do this.

Comment: You have $g_1(t)=e^{2t}v_1$ (for all real $t$) and supposedly $g_1$ is a solution to the differential equation, that is, $g_1'=Ag_1$, where $A$ is the square matrix in your question. To check if $g_1$ is a solution is to check whether $g_1'=Ag_1$ holds or not.

Comment: @GitGud but $g_1^1$ isn't a square matrix, so how could it ever be equal?

Comment: You have a complete eigenbasis for $A$—three linearly independent eigenvectors—so the matrix is diagonalizable. What do you know about the exponential of such a matrix?

Comment: @CluelessButCurious The LHS of the equality is the $3\times 1$ vector $g_1'$, the RHS is the $3\times 1$ vector $\underbrace{A}_{3\times 3}\underbrace{g_1}_{3\times 1}$.

Comment: @GitGud So it seems to work for every one, so I'm confused why in an example they do have to find a $u$

Comment: @CluelessButCurious Surely in the example the matrix isn't diagonalizable, you're "missing" eigenvectors, so you need to find some more. Making the link between this and your question, it's not the case of duplicate eigenvalues that is special, is the case of duplicate eigenvalues which "don't contribute" with enough eigenvectors. In your question $2$ comes up twice as an eigenvalues, but it also provides two eigenvectors.

Answer (score 1):

Given the matrix
$$\begin{pmatrix}
 11 & 6 & 18 \\
 9 & 8 & 18 \\
 -9 & -6 & -16 \\
\end{pmatrix}$$

We find the two eigenvalues (one is repeated) using $|A - \lambda I| = 0$, and get

$$\lambda_{1,2} = 2, \lambda_3 = -1$$

Next, find the eigenvectors using $[A - \lambda_i I]v_i = 0$.

Using Gaussian Elimination with $\lambda_{1,2} = 2$, we get a Row-Reduced-Echelon-Form (RREF) of

$$\begin{pmatrix}
 1 & \dfrac{2}{3} & 2 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{pmatrix}v_{1,2} = 0$$

Because we have a repeated eigenvalue, we now try to find two linearly independent eigenvectors from the RREF result of $a = -\dfrac{2}{3} b - 2c$. Fortunately, we can get two linearly independent eigenvectors by choosing  $b = 0, c = 1$ and also $c = 0, b = 3$, giving eigenvectors

$$v_1 = (-2, 0, 1)\\ v_2 = (-2, 3, 0)$$

As an aside, when we cannot find linearly independent eigenvectors, it is very important to learn the terms algebraic and geometric multiplicity, generalized eigenvectors and Jordan Form.

We repeat this process for the second eigenvalue $\lambda_3 = -1$ and find the third eigenvector

$$v_3 = (-1, -1 , 1)$$

As was mentioned in the comments by @amd, you have a complete eigenbasis for $A$, three linearly independent eigenvectors, so the matrix is diagonalizable. What do you know about the exponential of such a matrix?

Because of this, we can write the solution as

$$X(t) = c_1 e^{\lambda_1 t} v_1 + c_2 e^{\lambda_2 t} v_2 + c_3 e^{\lambda_3 t} v_3 = e^{2 t}\left(c_1 \begin{pmatrix}
 -2 \\ 0 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix} + c_2 \begin{pmatrix}
 -2 \\ 3 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix} \right) + c_3 e^{-t} \begin{pmatrix}
 -1 \\ -1 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix} $$

As was mentioned in the comments by @GitGud, that if we didn't have the two linearly independent eigenvectors, we would have had to find a generalized eigenvector or two and the solution would have been written as

$$X(t) =  c_1 e^{\lambda_1 t} v_1 + c_2 e^{\lambda_2 t}(tv_1 + v_2) + c_3 e^{\lambda_3 t} v_3 $$

You can find more examples and details of what are called defective matrices,
generalized eigenvectors and Jordan Form [*here*](http://mathcs.holycross.edu/~spl/old_courses/304_fall_2008/handouts/jordan.pdf)
 and [*here*](http://www.math.vt.edu/people/afkhamis/class_home/notes/F08W12.pdf) and [*here*](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-03sc-differential-equations-fall-2011/unit-iv-first-order-systems/matrix-methods-eigenvalues-and-normal-modes/MIT18_03SCF11_s33_8text.pdf).